# О какой "мышке" тут речь?

Tags: значение

В статье про контрабанду сыра [читаем](https://versia.ru/kak-organizovana-kontrabanda-molochnyx-produktov-iz-finlyandii-v-sankt-peterburg):

> Любопытно, данный «бизнес» в цепочке включает в себя как брутальных
> водителей фур, так и продвинутых гениев **«мышки»**.

В [викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C) вроде бы подходящего по смыслу значения нет?

Comment: Думаю, речь про гениальных пользователей компьютеров.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a (quite unsuccessful) attempt to use something else apart from "advanced computer users", this quote from the article makes it clearer:

> Если дальнобойщики закупаются и рискуют на границе, то мастера «мышки»
> уже делают умелый маркетинг в сети.